# What are the pros and cons of the HOC pattern vs React Hooks to inject props/dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dependency-injection, react-hooks, react-hoc

Suppose we have a HOC `withWidth` and a hook `useWidth` which both injects the current window width as a prop in a component.

`withWidth`:

```js
const MyFunctionComponent = withWidth(({width}) => {
  return width === 'mobile'
    ? // render mobile version
    : // render desktop version
});
```

`useWidth`:

```js
const MyFunctionComponent = () => {
  const width = useWidth();

  return width === 'mobile'
    ? // render mobile version
    : // render desktop version
};
```

What are the pros and cons both patterns? When should I prefer the one over the other?

The `withWidth` HOC solution isn't better at a Dependency Inversion Principle perspective? It's easier to mock the `width` dependency and to write tests, and the component itself doesn't have to handle the `width` creation.

And if it is, why we prioritize the usage of hooks? At least I often see this approach, prioritizing the usage of hooks instead of HOCs when possible.

I'm still learning about concepts of Dependency Inversion and stuff. These concepts often are examplified using Java, so transposing to JS and React world is quite difficult to me.